# Coverage permutation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

Is it possible to create coverpoints using various permutations of local variables ? Something like below

```
covergroup test1 with function sample(int i) ;  
  type_option.comment = "Config";
  int array1 [] = {0,1};
  int array2 [] = {3,4,9};
  int array3 [] = {5,6};
  coverpoint i
  {
    bins bin1 [] = {array1,array2};
    bins bin2 [] = {array2,array3};
  }
endgroup
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare local variables inside a covergroup, and you can't have array operations in a bin set. The closest you can do is

```
int array1 [] = {0,1};
int array2 [] = {3,4,9};
int array3 [] = {5,6};
int binset1[];
int binset2[];
covergroup test1 with function sample(int i) ;  
  type_option.comment = "Config";

  coverpoint i
  {
    bins bin1 [] = binset1;
    bins bin2 [] = binset2;
  }
endgroup
...
binset1 = {array1,array2};
binset2 = {array3,array4};
test1 = new();
```

Comment: Just watch out that not all simulators will support using class members (like `array1` or `array2`) inside bin expressions.

Comment: This doesn't work on 
`Compiler version = VCS H-2013.06-SP1-11
VCS Build Date = Nov 13 2014 20:55:33`

Comment: This works in Questa. What doesn't work about it in VCS? @Tudor I'm surprised a tool would care whether a bin value is from a class member or not. It's only going to look at the value once during construction.

Comment: @dave_59 I've seen all sorts of tool limitationswhile playing with coverage, each more exotic than the one before. @Jean Try passing in the bin arrays as constructor arguments to the covergroup or declaring them as `const`. This might work around limitations